# How to import com.fasterxml.jackson.core to the pom.xml file?

Tags: java, maven

I want to import a maven repository to these dependencies below:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.0</version>
   </dependency>
        
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
        
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

How do I import these dependencies from Maven and add to the pom.xml file
and add it to the repository-tags?

Comment: For the third time, you have asked more or less the same question. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

#### Importing Dependencies in pom.xml

- See the guide for how a pom is structured [HERE](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html)
- In this case, simply wrapping them in a `<dependencies>` tag and placing them as you see them

  - Assuming you already have a pom.xml file setup and merely need to add these?
  - Otherwise a full, very simple one might be below

    - Where the groupID, artifactId, and version are for your own stack/repot, i.e. that I named my stack `maven-test`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

#### Regarding Repositories

- Need more information on what you're trying to achieve, but the general introduction to Maven Repositories is [HERE](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)